# Document search from BigQuery based specific text?

Tags: google-bigquery

Here is my use case:
Employee profiles/resumes are stored in BigQuery.
The names of the employee needs to be returned when searched with a particular skill or skills.

Comment: Hey Chinmay, welcome to stackoverflow! Could you please share some example data of what you're working with so we can better advise? It would be helpful to share an example of what you're searching for also.

Comment: Name Resume (Stored as a document; one section has Skills: such as Python, Java, Salesforce, etc.)
————————————————-
John Doe Skills: Python
Jane Doe Skills: Java, Salesforce
 
I want to be able to search the name(s) when I search for a particular skill. 
For example: Searching for Python should return Jon Doe; Searching for Java should return Jane Doe

Answer (score 0):

For searching text within a field the `like` command is helpful.
There are many advanced ways to do this search task: regular expression, split the text by delimer, the `soundex` command (more usefull for different spelling of names).

At first the `with` creates a tempory table with your sample data. The `where skills like "%task_to_search%"` searches for the task and filters these datasets to be displayed only.

```
With tbl as 
(Select "Jane" as name, " Java, Salesforce" as skills
UNION ALL SELECT "John", "python"  )

SELECT *
from tbl
where lower(skills) like  "%java%"
```

Comment: I get your solution when the data is stored in a table. But, how about if the resume id stored in an unstructured format in GCP cloud storage?

Comment: Get the whole document in as a text column in the BigQuery table. Then search for the skill part in that text field. Please be aware that BigQuery cannnot handle all file formats, like microsoft word documents etc.